# How to run script at shutdown?

Tags: bash, shutdown

How can I make a bash script run only at shutdown?  I have searched for it and keep coming up empty handed. I would be fine with either a link or an explanation to how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you add script to `/etc/rc6.d/`

You might want to read `/etc/init.d/README`