# How to execute script on shutdown?

Tags: bash, shutdown

I want to execute script before I shutdown my machine that writes date to a file (so I do know what time I finish working).

How to do it?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/q/71991/5014)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute a script upon logout/reboot/shutdown in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is an init script: take a look at the [Upstart How to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto).

You basically need to place your script in `/etc/init.d` and create a link in `/etc/rc?.d`, where `"?"` is the runlevel you want to execute it.

The name of the link determines the order and when (start or shutdown) it's executed.
Links beginning with `K` are run on shutdown, beginning with `S` on startup. You should put the shutdown scripts in `/etc/rc0.d/`, and the startup scripts in `/etc/rc2.d/`. Restart scripts should be placed in `/etc/rc6.d`.

You could also execute a script when X ends or gnome logs you out, but I think init scripts are the cleanest solutions.

If going with the first option Debian based systems like Ubuntu provide the command line tool `update-rc.d` to assist with installing `/etc/rc?.d` scripts.