# Execute BASH script on shutdown

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, shutdown, kvm-virtualization

I have a KVM switch (Trendnet TK 409) that helps me switch between my Ubuntu laptop and Linux computer. The switch use a hotkey for switching (numlock+numlock).

Unfortunatly, that only works on Windows. I found a guide on the net, and have now a script called `kvm` (`etc/init.d`)

```
#!/bin/bash
numlockx on;
sleep 1; 
numlockx off;
sleep 1; 
numlockx on

exit 0
```

I have then attached a hotkey (ctrl+numlock) and this works perfectly..
But I would like to have done so that whenever I shutdown my Ubuntu computer, the script is executed so that I can continue on my windows computer.

As mentioned earlier `kvm` lies in `etc/init.d` and I have created a shortcut in `rc0.d` called `K99kvm`

But whenever I turn of my Ubuntu computer, the KVM doesnt switch to Windows computer. As I said the script itself works perfectly with hotkeys, but it doesnt work when turning the computer off.

Help would be much appreciated...

A small question aswell. Is it possible to create a hotkey in Ubuntu like numlock+numlock (2 clicks on the same button) and if yes, then how?

Comment: Here is a link to a previous question [run a script at shutdown][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83473/how-to-execute-script-on-shutdown

Comment: I have read the question you are linking to, and that is what i am trying to do, but it still doesnt works...

Comment: Nobody who can help me?