# There is any application that can be used to monitor for much time a computer is turned on?

Tags: software-recommendation, 13.04

I need an application that monitor how much time the computer is turned on. For example if I start the system at 12:03 AM and shut it down it at 3:16 PM and then in the same day I turn it on at 4:54 PM and shut it down at 7:47 PM, it would save this data so it could be reviewed later.

Do you know any application that perform such task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`uptime`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/uptime), and put a simple script like `uptime >> /home/user_name/.uptime` into `/etc/init.d/` and then make a symbolic link to it on `/etc/rc0.d/`, note that the script need to start with `K99`.

For more information on how to execute scripts before the system shut down see [How to execute script on shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83473/how-to-execute-script-on-shutdown).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `uptimed` which does exactly that. It's a daemon to record uptime records.

Install it by running following command in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install uptimed
```

Once installed you can use `uprecords` command to check your uptime records.