# How can I make Xubuntu automatically tally the number of times a machine loads?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, scripts, network-monitoring

I would like to pilot Xubuntu in a school computer lab environment. The solution requires shared access devices that are independent of the school's Windows environment. I would like to collect data comparing the usage of this lab compared to traditional Windows labs. Is there a script or command that can run on start up that will just keep a tally of how many times the machine is turned on?

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting the clear idea about your script but who ever login into that system will have their log with their username in  `/var/log/auth.log`

you can view the log by

```
sudo cat  /var/log/auth.log
```

So if you want to track their login/starting , make a backup command and run it before they logout/shutdown of your system.

[Execute a script upon logout/reboot/shutdown in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu)