# How to run a script at logout

Tags: unity, scripts, logout

I want to run a script when I log out through unity.  I read something about lightdm but I don't really know what it is and the config file didn't exist.
The config file mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu) doesn't exist! And manualy creating it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 9):

1. Open terminal ( or also known as command line ) by pressing together <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> or by finding it in dash.
2. Run this command `sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. This opens text editor with lightdm.conf file located in `/etc/lightdm` folder.
3. In the file you should have this line `[SeatDefaults]` . Bellow this line , enter `session-cleanup-script=/path/to/your-script.sh` , where /path/to/your-script.sh is the actuall address of the script that you want to run. Note: make sure your script is set to executable by running `sudo chmod +x /path/to/script.sh`
4. Save and exit

**NOTE**:  as of 14.04 version, the config file doesn't exist and must be created manually OR  copied from an example file using the following command

```
 sudo sh -c ' zcat /usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz > /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but this config file doesn't exist.

Comment: The solution [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/624489/410689) worked but the config file was not located in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` but in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf`.

Comment: In case the config file does not exist, I think you should just create it in this location. Don't forget to add the headline `[SeatDefaults]` as well then.

Comment: I've addressed the existence of the file issue