# Problem running backup script at shutdown Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, backup, shutdown

I want to run a script at shutdown, and a far as I can tell I've followed the proper procedures. The script (close) is supposed to launch another script (gdrive) in a terminal which prompts me to sync my Google drive folder.

Here's what I've done:

1. Copied files "close" and  and "gdrive" into /etc/init.d and made them executable.
2. Then I run the command `update-rc.d close start 0 0 .` from the command line. As expected this creates a link in `/etc/rc0.d` called `S00close` which points to the file `close`. Manually testing this link from the command line runs `close`, launches `gdrive` in a terminal and generally behaves as expected.

Unfortunately, nothing happens when I shutdown my machine.

Here is the code from `close`. In the first line I delay shutdown because I think the sync will take about 5 minutes or so:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S shutdown -c
xterm -e '/etc/init.d/gdrive'
```

Here is the code from gdrive (although, close doesn't run on shutdown, so I'm not sure how relevant this is):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Sync Gdrive?"
read response
if [ $response = "y" ]; then 
cd ~/Gdrive
drive push -ignore-name-clashes -quiet -ignore-conflict 
drive pull -ignore-name-clashes -quiet -ignore-conflict
echo "Drive successfully synced"
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S shutdown -h now
exit 1
else
echo "Ok, maybe next time"
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S shutdown -h now
exit 1
fi
```

I'm not super knowledgeable with this stuff, so any advice is appreciated. Even if someone could tell me how I can see what is happening at shutdown (what log files to look at etc.) that would be great.

Comment: I don't understand. `shutdown -c` will cancel a running `shutdown`, not delay it by 5 minutes. You also don't need `sudo`, that script will be run as `root`. Try replacing that script with one that simply contains `echo "foo" > /home/youruser/foo`. Just to make sure that a simple script will be launched as expected. Check if that created the file `foo` in your `$HOME`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have re-evaluated my strategy a little. I've just put a button in my launcher that runs the second script. This is much simpler and accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried [running a script at logout](http://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu) instead of shutdown??? :/

Answer (score 1):

OP has solved the problem:

> Thanks for replying. I have re-evaluated my strategy a little. I've
>   just put a button in my launcher that runs the second script. This is
>   much simpler and accomplishes the same thing.