# Ubuntu Screen rotation of 90° after successful login

Tags: screen, login-screen, fujitsu-siemens, rotate-monitor

As mentioned above, my screen loves to rotate 90 degrees after login. Standard Ubuntu installed.
This input turns it normal again:

`felix@felix-LIFEBOOK-T4220:~$ xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate normal`

I have to mention that this problem occured once I pressed the extra button for rotation. The button works like a charm but ince that, this prob just occured.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [confirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/meta-gnome3/+bug/1316901) in 14.04 after using the button, the screen rotates on the next restart. There's a workaround mentioned there to fix it.

an init-script, that removes monitors.xml and monitors.xml.backup on shutdown and reboot.

Start Gedit as root.

`sudo gedit`

Copy the following lines

```
#!/bin/sh
rm /home/USERNAME/.config/monitors.xml
rm /home/USERNAME/.config/monitors.xml.backup
rm /var/lib/lightdm/.config/monitors.xml
rm /var/lib/lightdm/.config/monitors.xml.backup
exit 0
```

Exchange USERNAME with your own and save the script in /etc/init.d.
File-name doesn't matter. I called it "orientation".

After that make the script executable.

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/orientation
```

And create a link to the script, so it gets executed on shutdown an reboot.

Comment: Thank you!
Link creation via sudo update-rc.d orientation start ?

Comment: this article may help you with that: [Execute a script upon shutdown/reboot/logout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu)