# Schedule command during shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, cron, reboot, logout, scheduled

How do we execute a command such as it executes everytime one logs out or shutdowns or restarts the machine ?

To be more specific, I want the autotrash to be executed at logout, or shutdown or restart.

Comment: Look at this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu

Comment: @EricPower Yes, this is a duplicate.

Comment: @EricPower Thank you for the link. Though it will work. is there a way in using cron ? Like without having to use `sudo`, and without affecting other users ?

Comment: @maan81: unfortunately cron knows only about time, not about startup/shutdown. See [crontab(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man5/crontab.5.html) for the details.