# I cannot boot Ubuntu 16.04 on MacBook Pro(Mid 2012, macOS Sierra)

Tags: 16.04, macosx, macbook-pro

I had updated my Mac 3 days back from Elcapitan to Sierra. I had dualboot(Ubuntu + OSX) and it was working perfectly with default boot as Ubuntu and by pressing option key I had OSX booted. But after update I cannot boot Ubuntu. I have important files in Ubuntu, please help me. Thanks.

Comment: That happened to me too, when I upgrade to Sierra. Had to do something to boot loader and switch priority of partition. The order of 0080 and 0000

Answer (score 0):

From [rEFInd menu not showing on a dual Mac/Ubuntu machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698606/refind-menu-not-showing-on-a-dual-mac-ubuntu-machine)

sudo efibootmgr -o 80,1

Last time, I seemed to use the liveUSB I used to install Lubuntu, choose try Lubuntu before installing, then open a terminal and run the command.