# rEFInd Boot Manager stopped working after installing Ubuntu 17- MacBook Pro Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, macbook-pro, refind

I just installed Ubuntu 17 on my mid-2012 MacBook Pro to dual boot with MacOS X. I'm new to Ubuntu. During installation I used rEFInd as a boot manager and it worked perfectly while testing Ubuntu on my computer, but after installing Ubuntu, rEFInd no longer works. I now have to use the option key to choose which OS to boot, and if I don't hold down the option key at startup, the computer automatically boots Ubuntu. Any help to get rEFInd working again as my boot manager would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as you. 
Resolved it by changing BootOrder using `efibootmgr` from within Ubuntu.

## Before

```
# sudo efibootmgr 
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0080
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0080* Mac OS X
Boot0081* Recovery OS
Boot0082* 
BootFFFF*
```

## Change order

```
# sudo efibootmgr -o 0080,0000
```

## After

```
# sudo efibootmgr 
BootCurrent: 0080
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0080,0000
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0080* Mac OS X
Boot0081* Recovery OS
Boot0082* 
BootFFFF*
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this. What worked for me was to re install rEFInd every time I installed a new OS. You may do so by launching a terminal inside the recovery mode and navigating to the rEFInd folder (usually on an external dev) where the installation file is, then you can run the installation file. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom (rEFInd worked at first then stopped working) on a Macbook Pro 13" retina (mid-2014). Running OS X Catalina and Mint 19.3, I installed rEFInd from within OS X after both were already working.

In my case rEFInd appeared after installation and let me pick each system one time, thereafter the system booted straight into Mint, but Opt on startup would show both bootable volumes.

I used [klippo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1032765/527764) and now it works as expected. `sudo efibootmgr` shows the current configuration, while `sudo efibootmgr -o 0080,0000` changes the boot order so that 0080 (MacOs in my case) is first. After that change rEFInd shows up on boot as expected.

See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/715043/682101).