# Run script on shutdown or restart

Tags: bash, scripts, shutdown, reboot

I would like some help getting a script to run on shutdown and restart.

Following advice I found online, I created the script and placed it in `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d`.

Unfortunately, the scripts are not running and when I run Aptitude, I see the following error appear:

```
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K99-CreateSuccessfulPowerOffFile
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K99-CreateSuccessfulPowerOffFile
```

Here are the contents of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo success > /etc/poweroffsuccess.txt
exit 0
```

And here are the permissions:

```
user@hostname:~$ ls -l /etc/rc0.d/K9*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 Sep 24 11:11 /etc/rc0.d/K99-CreateSuccessfulPowerOffFile

user@hostname:~$ ls -l /etc/rc6.d/K9*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 Aug 18 21:09 /etc/rc6.d/K99-CreateSuccessfulPowerOffFile
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 16.04, which is the latest version available for my platform (Odroid XU3).

Comment: Use the systemd method, instead of messing around with `/etc/init.d`: http://askubuntu.com/a/796157/158442

Answer (score 0):

If you read `/etc/rc0.d/README`, you'll see that you're not following the pattern.  First, your script should be in `/etc/init.d`, and there should be a symbolic link to it (created with the `ln` command) in `/etc/rc0.d` or `/etc/rc6.d`.  Also, the script should have a particular header as described in `/etc/init.d/README`.  All the scripts in my `/etc/init.d` are owned by root; I'm not sure if that's a requirement, but it couldn't hurt.  (The `chown` command is used to change ownership of a file.)