# How to enable a logging off sound in Ububtu 16.10

Tags: sound, 16.10

This is my first question on here so please don't destroy me, i would like to enable a logging off sound when turning off or restarting Ubuntu, i have some custom sounds installed and have managed to get system ready and logging ON to work, however all questions i have looked for regarding this are over 6 years old and don't actually address what I'm trying to do. I have a few different .ogg files and have basically deleted the old ones and pasted in the new.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/ , and look for the excellent systemd-related answer, for how to trigger an event upon logout in 16.04 and newer releases of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the program music123 to play the sound

```
sudo apt install music123
```

Then create a init file to trigger a file to play

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/K01sdsound.sh
```

In that file do something like

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/music123 /yourpath/yourfile.format
```

Make your file executable

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/K01sdsound.sh
```

Test your file

```
/etc/init.d/K01sdsound.sh
```

Now that your file plays a song or sound you need to tell it to run on logoff you can add it to your lightdm config, lets create a new config file

```
sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-sdsound.conf
```

add to this new file

```
[SeatDefaults]
session-cleanup-script=/etc/init.d/K01sdsound.sh
```

You now have sound on **logoff**

Or if you want it on **shutdown** create a symbolic link from your file to /etc/rc0.d so your system runs it on shutdown either/also

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/K01sdsound.sh /etc/rc0.d/K01sdsound.sh
```

Comment: Answers for new versions of Ubuntu should use systemd, not init.