# Periodically lock ssh keys while logged in

Tags: ssh, security

I use ssh daily to login to a couple servers I manage, and I use an ssh key to login. Because I generated my ssh key with a password, the first time I use ssh in a day, I'm prompted for a password. I want this to periodically lock again throughout the day, so that someone getting access to my laptop while it's on doesn't necessarily get access to the servers. I can't find an option for this, and I also can't figure out a command to lock the key. If there is such a command, I could add it to crontab.

Probably the best option is simply not to use an ssh key.

Comment: You should never leave a computer unattended. Lock it when you leave.

Comment: A couple of approaches off the top of my head would be to start your ssh session with a timeout so that it cuts out after a certain period, which is not very fine grained. The other option is to set the ssh server to log you out after a period inactivity. Neither of these are ideal, and both of them lead to a total disconnect which is why I've not gone with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a program called `ssh-agent` running. When you `ssh` to some 
other host, the `ssh` command communicates with that `ssh-agent` to maintain
the keys and their passphrases.

By default, the `ssh-agent` remebers the passphrases forever (until logout)
so you only have to enter it once for each key.

The command [`ssh-add`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ssh-add.1.html) is used to manage the list of identities the `ssh-agent`
knows about.

To show the list of keys the `ssh-agent` knows, issue

```
ssh-add -l
```

To make it *forget* your keys and passphrases, issue

```
ssh-add -D
```

When you then `ssh` into some host, you will again be prompted 
for the passphrase.

It is also possible to supply a *lifetime* for a passphrase:

```
ssh-add -t 3600     # 1 hour
```

but this didn't work for me (or I did something wrong). I'd setup
a cronjob that does `ssh-add -D` every N hours. This might be a bit tricky
because `ssh-add` needs the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to
communicate with the `ssh-agent` and that variable is presumably not 
set under cron.

But, as stated in a comment, you should not leave your laptop unattended
while you're away but rather lock it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write a line in your `$HOME/.bash_logout` file that moves your SSH key from your `~/.ssh/` directory into a different directory? Then do the opposite in `$HOME/.bash_login`.

[See this post about doing this with systemd.](https://askubuntu.com/a/796157/269670)