# Clear swap on every shutdown

Tags: swap

I would like to clear my swap on shutdown because I heard that swap does not get cleared like ram and any personal information on it could be preserved. I don't want to encrypt the swap as I had previous issues with that.

I know `sudo swapoff -a && sudo swapon -a` will clear the swap, but how can I get my PC to execute that on shutdown, is there some sort of script I can add this to? Or am I terribly mistaken and swap DOES get cleared?

Comment: Does this answer you question https://askubuntu.com/a/796157/8698 about running scripts on shutdown?

Comment: You could also simply turn off swap when using applications that handle personal data like browsers and email. Or change the nice level so those personal-data applications are less likely use swap than your massive protein-folding application.

Comment: This (clearing swap) is not worth doing unless you have a good Threat/Risk model, and have searched online for "recovering data from swap"

Comment: Thanks guys but recently I moved to Manjaro and encrypted the entire drive with LUKS so the encrypted swap is not an issue anymore. But thank you for your help!