# Execute a script upon a blank screen (screen off) in Ubuntu

Tags: suspend

Once the system is inactive, in 10 minutes it goes in a blank screen (but not in sleep!) and that's precisely the moment I'd like to execute a long-running script in a terminal while I go for a coffee or take a break.
When I come back and "wake up" the system (although technically it's not "sleeping"), I can manually stop the running program that has been executed at the screen off.

Example of such a command:

`/usr/bin/screen -S screen-off -dm my-command`

There is a bunch of similar questions ([Execute a script upon logout/reboot/shutdown in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu)) but they address services that are executed upon the sleep and wake up and this does not suit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dbus-monitor` you can watch for the screensaver signal like this:

```
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" |
  while read x; do
    case "$x" in 
      *"boolean true"*) echo "Start my script";;
      *"boolean false"*) echo "Cancel my script";;  
    esac
  done
```

Replace the `echo` statements with whatever you need, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Doesn't this answer introduce overhead by constantly polling the system `while read x`? I imagined a command that is run only once (at the interrupt, speaking of polling and interrupts).

Comment: @dizcza did you happen to figure out how to avoid the polling?

Comment: @Constantine nope, I didn't. The solution above satisfied my needs. There was another sharp answer that the non-polling solution will be me hitting a keyboard shortcut each time I go for a coffee. Don't know what happened to this strikingly smart comment.

Comment: This actually monitors the screensaver state, and not the state of the screen.