# (r)sync between Ubuntu virtual machine and windows host using a shared folder (after start and before restart/shutdown

Tags: 22.04, cron, systemd, rsync

The host machine is windows. I have an Ubuntu virtual machine(vmware). There is a shared folder between Ubuntu and Windows.
The shared folder is mounted in `/etc/fstab`:

```
vmhgfs-fuse                  /shared    fuse    defaults,allow_other,nofail
```

When Ubuntu virtual machine start(after)/restart(before)/shutdown(before), if `shared` is mounted I want to sync(rsync) certain directories from Ubuntu in the shared folder.

Example:

```
/work/alpha to be rsync in /shared/alpha
```

I tried the code below and variations but is not working:

file: rsync_before_shutdown.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -r /workspace/projects/ /shared
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Run before shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true 
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /workspace/projects/rsync_before_shutdown.sh/rsync_before_shutdown.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I'm checking journalctl after reboot:

```
run_before_shutdown.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start Run before shutdown.
```

I presume that the reason can be the directory is unmounted when the script tries to run.

So, I changed the target from `shutdown.target` to `unmount.target`. ?It is working only if the reboot is done by root.
The permission on the service is 644 and on the script `rwxr-xr-x`

Comment: See [this question and it's answers for possible solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu) how to run scripts at system start up and shutdown.

Comment: try `Before=umount.target` instead of `shutdown.target`

Comment: @kanehekili it work but only if user is root

Comment: Yes, that is to be expected. The services run as root. On a GUI you could shut down via Menu, so how do you shutDown? So your script could be either moved to root or you change user & group: `chown root:root /path/to/your/rsync_before_shutdown.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following in a VBox with Ubuntu 22.04 running.

Create a systemd service in /etc/systemd/system/actionPreShutDown.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run before shutdown
#DefaultDependencies=no
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true 
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/sync_before_shutdown.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Create the testfile `/usr/local/bin/sync_before_shutdown.sh`

Mine looked like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
timestamp=$(date '+%n---%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y---%n')
SOURCE=`dirname -- "$0"`;
echo $SOURCE
echo "Shutting down now: '$timestamp'" >>$SOURCE/log.txt
```

so it basically wrote a log (into the still mounted filesystem) on "poweroff".

The "Poweroff" was triggered via the gnome menu and via command line.

Why `/usr/local/bin`?

The code to be executed must belong to the system, **not** the user. Since I consider "backups" an admin task and the [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html) writes:

> The /usr/local hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when
> installing software locally. It needs to be safe from being
> overwritten when the system software is updated.

The bash will be in your path (i.e. you can call it from the console), but can only be executed as root.

But my final answer is, that it might not work stable. Poettering [himself](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/12257) could not answer the question...

The main problem seems to be that there is no way to execute code before umount, since systemd runs parallel and shutdown and umount are triggered independently of each other. So I focused on available mounts and targets.

The line `After=local-fs.target` enables the service **after** that target is bound, and therefore will end it **before** that target will be removed/stopped.

As an alternative you might setup your mount points from where you want to backup and proceed like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89881/systemd-umount-device-after-service-which-depends-on-it-finishes).
Since I spend a lot of time on this issue I'd appreciate an update if you found another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently used Rsync to backup files from my old 16.04 PC to another PC with 22.04 using `rsync -av -e ssh old_user@old_laptop:/home/old_user/ /home/new_user` but you need to have `openssh-server` installed on the PC your coming from.

To use Rsync on Windows you may need the `Windows Subsystem for Linux` or WSL for short installed or `Git for Windows` which will let you call Rsync with git bash.

Frankly I think this is all unnecessary as there are programs out there already that allow you to setup real-time sync changing files from source directory to target directory in real time.

Perhaps look at Syncthing and SyncTrayzor.

Comment: it is a virtual machine an there is mounted a shared folder between the Ubuntu vm and Windows host, so the Ubuntu sees as a normal folder in Linux. No ssh needed or WSL. I don't need to be in real time but when the vm is shutdown/restarted.