# Make Ubuntu wait for service to stop before rebooting

Tags: 22.04, shutdown, services

I have a mini pc running Kubernetes (k3s) with homeassistant.

### The issue leading to the question

When I do a sudo reboot (forgetting that the home assistant is running) the sqlite database becomes corrupted, presumably because it is writing to it as I am rebooting.

### The question

Is there a mechanism to make Ubuntu wait for a service to shut down gracefully, to avoid this in the future?

Comment: Don't use `sudo reboot`, use `sudo shutdown -r now` to reboot gracefully.

Comment: isn't `sudo reboot` just a wrapper for `sudo shutdown -r now`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad. However, the service ought to be shut down gracefully then. I can't explain why that doesn't happen.

Comment: You'll probably find what you're looking for here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu